# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'test'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have this cell I'm trying to run in my jupyter notebook:

```
# Comparison of different techniques for the winner prediction
# Interval for the comparison : [beg,end]
beg=datetime(2013,1,1)
end=data.Date.iloc[-1]
indices=data[(data.Date>=beg)&(data.Date<=end)].index
# classical ATP ranking
test=data[["WRank","LRank"]].iloc[indices,:]
atp=100*(test.LRank>test.WRank).sum()/len(indices)
# Elo ranking
test=data.iloc[indices,:]
elo=100*(test.elo_winner>test.elo_loser).sum()/len(indices)
# Bookmakers
test=data.iloc[indices,:]
book_pi=100*(test.PSW<test.PSL).sum()/len(indices)
book_365=100*(test.B365W<test.B365L).sum()/len(indices)
# Our prediction
our=100*conf.win0.sum()/len(conf)
# Plot
labels=["Prediction with ATP ranking","with Elo ranking",
        "Bet365","Pinnacle",
        "our prediction"]
values=[atp,elo,book_pi,book_365,our]
xaxis_label="% of matches correctly predicted"
title="Prediction of all matches since Jan. 2013 ("+str(len(indices))+" matches)"
xlim=[65,70]
basic_horizontal_barplot(values,labels,xaxis_label,title,xlim,figsize=(4,4))
```

However, every time I do, I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [51], in <cell line: 11>()
      9 # Elo ranking
     10 test=data.iloc[indices,:]
---> 11 elo=100*(test.elo_winner>test.elo_loser).sum()/len(indices)
     12 # Bookmakers
     13 test=data.iloc[indices,:]

File D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'test'
```

I am relatively new to python , and ive been trying to debug the error but i still havent come up with a solution yet. Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you share complete code

Comment: I have uploaded the full code. @Akashgarg

Comment: What does the data frame 'data' look like, could you share few rows from it